# How do I prevent my users from hacking my web game?

Tags: javascript, client

I'm currently making a multiplayer game that runs entirely with web technologies. I know that the only way to make cheating hard is to have logic that's mostly **server-side**, as you cannot trust that the users won't alter your client-side code.
However, this is just a little project, I don't really care if it's not 100% safe, and making 100% of the game's logic server-side is definitely out of the question.

The solution that I want to implement is this:
Making the client-side code nearly impossible to alter, nearly impossible to understand, and disconnect the client whenever it's clear that he is interacting with the website in a way that should not be possible.

It doesn't have to be perfect, it just has to be hard enough that literally **no one** would care enough to try. I have a lot of programmer friends so I know for a fact that they're going to try and break everything...

How can I achieve this?
Does this practice even have a name ?
Would you guys have resources where I can learn how to do this, or have experience with this ?

Thanks !
dFuZer

Comment: It is called security through obscurity  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity

Comment: Look into obfuscation. Anything else requires server-side involvement which you seem to want to avoid.

Comment: Thinking about users hacking "your game" is really, i hate to say, in the land of law and courts. You can sue someone stealing your code and making a living off stolen code. Sure you can have regular security, but if I myself work for you, how are you going to stop me?

Comment: I don't think you can detect "_[a user] is interacting with the website in a way that should not be possible_". A user can even make changes to your script and run the page with their own script.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I don't think obfuscation is quite enough, as people can just look at the websocket trafic from their chrome developer tools. I'm fine with doing some verifications server-side, I just don't want to implement the whole game's logic there because it's a lot harder.